# How do I resolve OpenCV Error capturing images in thread?

Tags: windows, multithreading, opencv, webcam

I have multiple sources for OpenCV Videocapture and want to load this each in a different thread. Now, the loading of images and movies are good, but the webcams give me empty images. This only occurs when I do this in threads. In the situation that I use the same code without a thread I receive images from the webcam. OpenCV gives me the following error:

`[ERROR:0] VIDEOIO(makePtr<VideoCapture_DShow>(index)): raised unknown C++ exception!`

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

```
class render(threading.Thread):

    def __init__ (self, _scene):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.scene = _scene

    def renderWebcam(self,src):
        camera = cv2.VideoCapture(src+cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
        camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1280)
        camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720)

        while True:
            try:
                rc,image = camera.read()
                img = cv2.resize(image,(640,360))
                cv2.imwrite('renderfiles/Totaal.png', img)
                crop = image[100:460, 100:740]
                img = cv2.resize(crop,(640,360))
                cv2.imwrite('renderfiles/Ingezoomd.png', img)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break;
        camera.release();
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I use python 2.7 on windows 10 and logitech webcams

**Update:**
The minimum setup where this error occurs is:

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2

def renderWebcam(src,name):
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(src+cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

    while True:
        try:
            rc,image = camera.read()
            img = cv2.resize(image,(640,360))
            cv2.imwrite('renderfiles/'+name+'.png', img)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break;
    camera.release();
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

thread = Thread(target=renderWebcam, args=(0,'Webcam1')) 
thread.start()
thread = Thread(target=renderWebcam, args=(1,'Webcam2')) 
thread.start()
```

Comment: I don't know the official position but I have never succeeded in running `imshow()` in multiple threads. I have always found I have to push all images to a single thread for display. YMMV.

Comment: I don't use imshow, but imwrite. Just writing the images to the filesystem

Comment: Can you complete that example to make it a proper [mcve]? Do I understand it correctly that to reproduce you need to have at minimum two USB cameras, and two of those threads running? What version of OpenCV?

Comment: For MCV-example, see update in the question. I use python 2.7 and opencv 4.0.1

Comment: I found I can run multiple threads if not specifying the CAP_DSHOW backend, however the output resolution is poor and I cant configure if not specifying Directshow. If I use CAP_DSHOW , I can set the resolution ok but threading fails when it tries to open the second camera.  Catch 22.